# How to send requests to api in batches in logic app

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I have a logic app in which I create a json request using javascript inline code and send that to an api. The json request might have more than 1000 requests in it. I need to send those requests in the batches of 200 to api. How do I achieve batching in logic app?

Comment: Hi, I'm not so clear about your situation, could you please provide more details of your javascript inline code ? Do you mean separate 1000 json records to five 200 records and use foreach in js inline code to loop the five request ?

Comment: Yes I am doing this currently, var field = Object.keys(workflowContext.trigger.outputs.body.Attributes);
var key = 'key';
var items = workflowContext.trigger.outputs.body.AttributeGroups[key]['Items'].Items;
var ids= [];
for (var i = 0; i <  items.length; i++){
    ids.push(items[i]['Id']['Value'])
}
var ID1 = workflowContext.actions.tag.outputs.body[0].id;
var json = {};
json.records = new Array();
 for(var i in ids)
 {
    json.records.push({
     "attributes" : {
     "Id": ids[i]
     },
    "Property": ID1 ,
          "Type": ids[i]
    });
}   
return json;

Comment: I want to generate multiple json array in the sizes of 200

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this requirement, please refer to the js code below:

```
//First define a function to do the separate arry operation
function group(array, subGroupLength) {
    let index = 0;
    let newArray = [];
    while(index < array.length) {
        newArray.push(array.slice(index, index += subGroupLength));
    }
    return newArray;
}

//Then use the "group(array, subGroupLength)" function to separate your array to multiple 200 records array
var resultArray = group(json.records, 200);

return resultArray;
```

Afer the code, the resultArray should be like:

```
[
  [
    {
        "attributes": {
            "Id": ""
        },
        "Property": ID1,
        "Type": ""
    },
    .....
    //200 items
    .....
    {
        "attributes": {
            "Id": ""
        },
        "Property": ID1,
        "Type": ""
    }
  ],
  ....
  //five sub array
  ....
  [
    {
        "attributes": {
            "Id": ""
        },
        "Property": ID1,
        "Type": ""
    },
    .....
    //200 items
    .....
    {
        "attributes": {
            "Id": ""
        },
        "Property": ID1,
        "Type": ""
    }
  ]
]
```

===============================**Update**===========================

For your new requirement about `give all those sub arrays a name(same name for all sub arrays)`, I modified the code of `function group(array, subGroupLength)` like below:

```
function group(array, subGroupLength) {
    let index = 0;
    let newArray = [];
    while(index < array.length) {
        let item = array.slice(index, index += subGroupLength);
        let itemObj = {"subArray": item};
        //newArray.push(array.slice(index, index += subGroupLength));
        newArray.push(itemObj);
    }
    return newArray;
}
```

In my code, the name for each sub array is `subArray`. Please check if it meet your requirement.

Comment: Thank you very much for spending the time and looking into it! I did the similar way, I also wanted to give all those sub arrays a name. Same name for all sub arrays, is that possible while creating array?

Comment: Hi @Mm77 I have updated my answer, please take a look.